# connect signal emitted from c++ to qml Connections

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcontext

I am emitting a signal from c++ and trying to fetch the values using Connections in qml. The codes are compiling however, due to some unknown reason qml is not able to recognise "**OnSomethingHappened**" and signal emitted from c++ is "**somethingHappened**".

I know there can be other solutions but i need to use connections in qml. This is because of architecture used in qml.

qmlclient.h

```
#ifndef QMLMQTTCLIENT_H
#define QMLMQTTCLIENT_H

#include <QtCore/QMap>
#include <QtMqtt/QMqttClient>
#include <QtMqtt/QMqttSubscription>

class QmlMqttClient;

class QmlMqttSubscription : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QMqttTopicFilter topic MEMBER m_topic NOTIFY topicChanged)
public:
    QmlMqttSubscription(QMqttSubscription *s, QmlMqttClient *c);
    ~QmlMqttSubscription();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void topicChanged(QString);
    void messageReceived(QString &msg);
    void somethingHappened(QString text);

public slots:
    void handleMessage(const QMqttMessage &qmsg);

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QmlMqttSubscription)
    QMqttSubscription *sub;
    QmlMqttClient *client;
    QMqttTopicFilter m_topic;
};

class QmlMqttClient : public QMqttClient
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QmlMqttClient(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QmlMqttSubscription *subscribe(const QString &topic);

    void sub();
private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QmlMqttClient)
};


#endif // QMLMQTTCLIENT_H*/
```

qmlmqttclient.cpp

```
#include "qmlmqttclient.h"
#include <QDebug>

QmlMqttClient::QmlMqttClient(QObject *parent)
    : QMqttClient(parent)
{
}

QmlMqttSubscription* QmlMqttClient::subscribe(const QString &topic)
{
    auto sub = QMqttClient::subscribe(topic, 0);
    auto result = new QmlMqttSubscription(sub, this);
    return result;
}

QmlMqttSubscription::QmlMqttSubscription(QMqttSubscription *s, QmlMqttClient *c)
    : sub(s)
    , client(c)
{
    connect(sub, &QMqttSubscription::messageReceived, this, &QmlMqttSubscription::handleMessage);
   // m_topic = sub->topic();
}

QmlMqttSubscription::~QmlMqttSubscription()
{

}

void QmlMqttSubscription::handleMessage(const QMqttMessage &qmsg)
{
    //emit messageReceived(qmsg.payload());

    emit somethingHappened(qmsg.payload());

    qDebug() << "value -> " + qmsg.payload();
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QmlMqttClient *client =  new QmlMqttClient();
    client->setHostname("127.0.0.1");
    client->setPort(1883);

    client->connectToHost();
    qDebug() << client->state();

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [client]() {client->subscribe("/root/temp");});
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    timer.start(5000);



    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel",client);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: sensor
        color: "#ffffff"
        radius: 10
        x: 10
        y: 10

        property string address
        property string title
        property string unit

        Text{
            id: textField

            property var value : 0

            text: sensor.title + " " + value + " " + sensor.unit
            y:50
            font.family: "Helvetica"
            font.pointSize: 24
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }

        Connections
        {
            target: myModel

            onSomethingHappened: {
             console.log(" something happened " +text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running the above codes console shows

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
1
qrc:/main.qml:33:9: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onSomethingHappened"
"value -> -50"
"value -> -50"
"value -> -50"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal you're trying to connect to is in `QmlMqttSubscription` class but your context property `myModel` object is of type `QmlMqttClient`.

```
QmlMqttClient *client =  new QmlMqttClient();
...
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel",client);
```

Comment: hi thank you for finding the fault. But i am wondering how can i emit the signal declared in say QmlMqttClient from handle message slot

Comment: @Mandeep Well, `emit` is actually just a macro which evaluates to nothing, so "emitting" a signal is essentially like invoking any other class method. So in theory you could "emit" any public method of any class. But this is typically not a good design because it breaks "encapsulation" expectancy.  From your example I don't understand how `QmlMqttSubscription` even comes into play here (don't see it being used), so it is hard to advise further.

Comment: its k i found the solution. What i did is created a slot in client and connecting it on message recieved.  QmlMqttSubscription is used whenever there is a new subscription from client class. I cannot use any of them as base class because they are using each other and using one of them as base class may cause interdependencies cyclic error.

Comment: This is from qt examples provided for QMqtt